# Is it possible to require both glob and magic specified in mimetype definition?

Tags: wildcards, xml, mime-types, freedesktop

Given the following [freedesktop shared-mime-info file](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/shared-mime-info-spec/latest/ar01s02.html#idm45809472955424):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info">
    <mime-type type="application/x-example">
        <comment>Example file type </comment>
        <magic priority="50">
            <match value="search-string" type="string" offset="10:140"/>
        </magic>
        <glob weight="100" pattern="*.newextension"/>
    </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

Any file (regardless of the contents) with extension `newextension` will be detected as `application-x-example`. Files with any name and the appropriate contents work fine as well, but that's beside the point.

Is there a way to require both the glob pattern and the magic's search-string?